# React material ui date picker disable all dates in year except for the last day on everry month

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've been trying to figure out a way to only let the users select the last day of every month of a year (disabling the rest of the days). with the use of material ui date picker, was not able to find a proper solution to it. I would really appreciate if any one be able to show me how to implement this, thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you meant say on the post, but there's prop called onMonthChange on material Ui DatePicker API docs, you can get the relevant month details with this, then you can use the shouldDisableDate prop to disable the rest of the days other than the last date of the month.

refer Material Ui DatePicker API docs here https://next.material-ui.com/api/date-picker/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to let the users select the last day of every month of a year (disabling the rest of the days) with material ui date picker (like `DateTimePicker` or `KeyboardDatePicker`).

You could define an interval of valid dates (using props `minDate` and `maxDate`).

Another thing you can do is allow user to select all dates and then manage valid/invalid date using `onChange` event.